# How to execute multiple queries after each other?

Tags: php, mysql

The following should happen when a user fills the signup form and hits the signup button on the front-end. It should save all user info from the input fields to `users` table, then check if any records exists in the `userRole` table, if not insert `admin`, if yes insert `user` in the userRole column.

Basically is one insertion, one selection and again one insertion.
I don´t know how to setup this so this works. Right now only inserts in userRole table the value user.

```
 <?php

    // Get the userimage and save it with a unique id
    $sFileExtension = pathinfo($_FILES['fileUserImage']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $sFolder = 'img_webshop/';
    $sFileName = 'userimage-'.uniqid().'.'.$sFileExtension;
    $sSaveFileTo = $sFolder.$sFileName;
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileUserImage']['tmp_name'], $sSaveFileTo);

    try {

                // connect to the database
                require 'connect.php';
                // create a query
                $sUserName = $_POST['txtEmailorPhoneNumber'];
                $sFirstName = $_POST['txtFirstName'];
                $sLastName = $_POST['txtLastName'];
                $sPassword = $_POST['txtPassword'];
                $sImage = $sFolder.$sFileName;
                $query1 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users ( userName, firstName, lastName, password, image ) VALUES ( :userName, :firstName, :lastName, :password, :image )");
                $query1->bindParam( ':userName' , $sUserName );
                $query1->bindParam( ':firstName' , $sFirstName );
                $query1->bindParam( ':lastName' , $sLastName );
                $query1->bindParam( ':password' , $sPassword );
                $query1->bindParam( ':image' , $sImage );
                // run the query
                $aResult = $query1->execute();
                $query2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT ( userRole ) as total FROM userRoles");
                $bResult = $query2->execute();
                if ($bResult === 0 ) {
                    $sUserRole = 'admin';
                }
                else {
                    $sUserRole = 'user';
                }
                $query3 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO userRoles ( userRole ) VALUES ( :userRole )");
                $query3->bindParam( ':userRole' , $sUserRole );
                $cResult = $query3->execute();
                $sjResponse = $cResult ? '{"status":"ok"}' : '{"status":"error"}';
                // $lastId = $query->lastInsertId();
                // $result = json_encode( $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) );

                echo $sjResponse; 


            } catch (Exception $e) {

                echo "ERROR";

            }

    ?>
```

Comment: If you're using PDO, just drop `bindParam()` and pass the variables via `execute()`, and you can just loop through many `execute()` functions.

Comment: Where you are trying to check for userRoles records, you call `$query2->execute()`, but don't actually call `$query2->fetch()` to get the data. This may just by luck work - but it's not correct.

Comment: **Never** store plain text passwords. Instead use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). If you're using a version of PHP prior to 5.5, do **not** use MD5 or SHA1 to hash passwords. Instead you can use [this compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```html
if ($bResult === 0 ) {
$sUserRole = 'admin';
}
else {
 $sUserRole = 'user';
}
```

To this:

```html
if ($bResult > 0 ) {
$sUserRole = 'user';
}
else {
 $sUserRole = 'admin'; 
}
```

This should fix it!

Comment: in this way I only get `admin` inserted each time I run it, the other way only  `user`. seems like the row check  does not work properly.

Comment: try to echo "$bResult->total" If you get a number then change the code from if ($bResult > 0 ) to if ($bResult->total > 0 )